# QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName returns me a boolean.I'm trying to connect two functions in Python QT5 but I'm having some troubles

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I started coding a few weeks ago.

I want to do a function to clean some data in Python and I want to send it to coworkers use.
I used Qt5 to make an interface but I have some troubles to finish it.

First of all I'm creating a function to open the file, creating a variable to recieve this dateframe (csv).

After I have created another function, called "cleaner" to clean my data. But, before start coding the script to clean the data, I tried to print the dataframe just to see what happened. But when ask to print it, I got a boolean character, and no the dataframe I want. Like "False".

[image: Console shows me it]

````
from interpy import *
import resource
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QPushButton, QLabel,QFileDialog,QVBoxLayout
def main(ui):  
    def browseFile(self):
        filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File', '*.csv')
    ui.pushButton_arquivo.clicked.connect(browseFile)
    def cleaner(filename):
        print(filename)
    ui.pushButton_Submit.clicked.connect(cleaner)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting `False` because you are not passing in the filename argument in `cleaner`. What if you tried this:

```
def main(ui):  
    def browseFile(self):
        self.filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '*.csv')
    ui.pushButton_arquivo.clicked.connect(browseFile)
    def cleaner(self):
        print(self.filename)
    ui.pushButton_Submit.clicked.connect(cleaner)
```

Comment: Ira H. I tried but it didn't work. There was this error. 
  File "C:\Users\joao_\Desktop\data\programa.py", line 19, in cleaner
    print(self.filename)

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'filename'

Comment: Ok, if you print ```self.filename``` right after the ```QFileDialog```, does it return ```False```?

Comment: yes. but when I tried putting '''filename=QtWidgets...
print(filename)'''

it returned me "runfile('C:/Users/joao_/Desktop/data/programa.py', wdir='C:/Users/joao_/Desktop/data')

('C:/Users/joao_/Downloads/responses (7).csv', '*.csv')"

But don't know what to do with it too.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code above to replace ```.getOpenFileName(None, ...``` to ```.getOpenFileName(self, ...```. Does that help?

Comment: when I tried with "self" it happened:


"TypeError: getOpenFileName(parent: QWidget = None, caption: str = '', directory: str = '', filter: str = '', initialFilter: str = '', options: Union[QFileDialog.Options, QFileDialog.Option] = 0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'"

Comment: perhaps pass ```self``` as the first argument in ```main```?

Comment: it returned : NameError: name 'self' is not defined